# How to improve performance of multiple count queries in a laravel view

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm working on a marketing application that allows users to message their contacts. When a message is sent, a new "processed_message" database entry is created. There is a list view that displays all campaigns and the number of messages sent, blocked and failed for each campaign. My problem is that this list view takes way too long to load after there are > 50 campaigns with lots of messages.

Currently each campaign has 3 computed attributes (messages_sent, messages_failed and messages_blocked) that are all in the Campaign model's "appends" array. Each attribute queries the count of processed_messages of the given type for the given campaign.

```
namespace App;

class Campaign
{
    protected $appends = [
        'messages_sent',
        'messages_blocked',
        'messages_failed'
    ];

    /**
     * @relationship
     */
    public function processed_messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProcessedMessage::class);
    }

    public function getMessagesSentAttribute()
    {
        return $this->processed_messages()->where('status', 'sent')->count();
    }

    public function getMessagesFailedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->processed_messages()->where('status', 'failed')->count();
    }

    public function getMessagesBlockedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->processed_messages()->where('status', 'blocked')->count();
    }
}
```

I also tried to query all of the messages at once or in chunks to reduce the number of queries but getting all of the processed_messages for a campaing at once will overflow memory and the chunking method is way too slow since it has to use offset. I considered using eager loading the campaigns with processed_messages but that would obviously use way too much memory as well.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CampaignController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $start = now();
        $campaigns = Campaign::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
        $ids = $campaigns->map(function($camp) {
            return $camp->id;
        });

        $statistics = ProcessedMessage::whereIn('campaign_id', $ids)->select(['campaign_id', 'status'])->get();
        foreach($statistics->groupBy('campaign_id') as $group) {
            foreach($group->groupBy('status') as $messages) {
                $status = $messages->first()->status;
                $attr = "messages_$status";
                $campaign = $campaigns->firstWhere('id', $messages->first()->campaign_id);
                $campaign->getStatistics()->$attr = $status;
            }
        }

        return view('campaign.index', [
            'campaigns' => $campaigns
        ]);
    }
}
```

My main goal is to reduce the current page load time considerably (which can take anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 minutes when there are a bunch of campaigns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `withCount` method to count all the objects without loading the relation.

Reference:

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

In your controller you could  do this:

```
$count = Campaign::withCount(['processed_messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'sent');
}])->get();
```

You could do multiple counts in the same relationship too:

```
$campaigns = Campaign::withCount([
'processed_messages',
'processed_messages as sent_message_count' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'sent');
}],
'processed_messages as failed_message_count' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'failed');
}],
'processed_messages as blocked_message_count' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'blocked');
}])->get();
```

You can access the count with this:

```
echo $campaigns[0]->sent_message_count
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: How would I go about using the 2nd method if I wanted to load all 3 of the relations?

Comment: You could pass an array as a parameter of this method

Comment: But what keys will the resulting model use for the attribute? If I do the count 3 times wouldn't it just save all of the results in a column called "processed_messages_count" and only the last one will apply? Is there a way to customize the count attribute ({relation}_count) name?

Comment: yes, you can costumize this attribute, i edited my answer, take a look

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The first code block you have does not actually work (method withCount does not exist) but the second one sped up my tests by a large margin and in my case, I don't even have to load the "processed_messages" relation.

Comment: My mistake, this is a collection method, and  you can't use with ```$this``` in that case. But I'm glad that my answer helped you. Good luck on your project.